# Using Multiple Where In Same Name

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

**I have input like  this :**

```
<input type="text" value="Jake" name="name[]">
<input type="text" value="Boby" name="name[]">
```

**The Problem is :**
Using whereIn the result like using orWhere, but here i want to get the data where name is Jake && Boby, not Jake or Boby.

**I have tried this :**

```
Users::whereIn('name',request()->name)->get();
```

**I want to like this :**

```
Users::where('name','Jake')
       ->where('name','Boby')
       ->get();
```

Please Help Me To Resolve This, Thank You

Comment: Your problem statement is not clear. Please explain the problem in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the names and add them to the builder.

```
$userBuilder = Users::query();

foreach (request()->name as $name) {
    $userBuilder->where('name', $name);
}

$result = $userBuilder->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$nameArr = array();
foreach(request()->name as $name){
    $nameArr[] = $name;
}
$users = User::whereIn('name', $nameArr)->get();
```

See [Documentation Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)